# Mechanics of a levitating platform in Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

The essence of this mechanics is as follows:
Any object that has a Rigidbody2D, of any mass (that not exceeding the load capacity of the platform)
falls from any height onto the "levitating platform", the platform will take over this force and will go down, but, with the appropriate speed, will return to its original position.

Remarks: If the weight of the load exceeds the load capacity of the platform, the motor shuts down and the platform falls.
We should also consider the case of several objects on one platform.

I tried to implement this in several different ways:
In my opinion, the Spring Joint 2D component was able to implement this mechanic best, but the problem is that
The more cargo, the lower the platform goes and it doesn't come back up.

+- successful implementation with AddForce:
[Demo of My implementation](https://youtu.be/RNDllGWYmXs)
(But the platform is constantly moving as soon as it receives the load, so the video shows how the character does not land on it)

Could you please tell me how to do it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about a built in Unity solution, but here's what I'd do.

First you'll need a variable `float downness;`

In the OnCollisionEnter2D method you can subtract from this variable.

```
downness -= collision.rigidbody.Mass * 9.81;
```

Then, in the Update method, you can add this variable to the position each update.

```
transform.position += new Vector3(0, downness, 0) * Time.deltaTime;
```

Finally, since you want the platform to go back up, you just need to add to the variable. This is also in the Update method. You can play around with values for `resistance` to get it feeling how you want.

```
if (transform.position.y < desiredPosition.y)
    downness += resistance * Time.deltaTime;
else
{
    transform.position = desiredPosition;
    downness = 0;
}
```

Also, if you want it to fall after a certain threshold, just check if the variable (i.e. `downness`) is too low. Then you can stop the other operations and make it begin accelerating downwards with.

```
transform.position += new Vector3(0, -9.81f, 0) * Time.deltaTime;
```

Here's the script I used to test this.

```
public float Resistance = 20;
public float Threshold = -15;
    
float _downness;
Vector3 _desiredPosition;

const float _gravity = -9.81f;

void Start() => _desiredPosition = transform.position;

void Update()
{
    if (_downness > Threshold)
    {
        transform.position += new Vector3(0, _downness * Time.deltaTime);
        if (transform.position.y < _desiredPosition.y)
            _downness += Resistance * Time.deltaTime;
        else
        {
            transform.position = _desiredPosition;
            _downness = 0;
        }
    }
    else
        transform.position += new Vector3(0, _gravity, 0) * Time.deltaTime;
}

private void OnMouseDown() => _downness -= 10;
```